# In the phrase "per-diem rate," is the hyphen appropriate?

Tags: grammar

I am a proofreader and am confused as to why the hyphen I inserted between per and diem in "per diem rates" was stetted, since this would be a compound adjective. Was I wrong?

Comment: When a two-word descriptor is a common phrase, the hyphen is often left out.  Would you write "an ice-cream truck"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The US Department of State does not use a hyphen.

See:
  [Foreign Per Diem Rates by Location](http://aoprals.state.gov/web920/per_diem.asp)

Answer (score 2):

Punctuation is a matter of style, and as such you should be guided by your manual of style.  I use the *Chicago Manual of Style*, which recommends that in compound phrases, words of foreign origin follow the hyphenation in the language of origin.  Thus

> *per diem* rate

but

> *laissez-faire* economic policy